# Capistrano 3.8.1 deployment from windows

Tags: ruby, windows, capistrano

I've attempted to upgrade our capistrano2 script to latest capistrano, was however struggling to get it to work. In order to limit any problems with the conversion i started an empty project and did `cap install`.

Added a custom task to run locally on the machine and tried it. Same result.

This is the error I'm getting: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /usr/bin/env dir`

Exact instructions:

1) mkdir capdemo

2) cd capdemo

3) cap install

4) create file under lib/capistrano/tasks/foo.rake with this content:

`namespace :foo do
  desc "Foo"
  task :local do
      run_locally do
          execute :dir
      end
  end
end`

5) Run `cap staging foo:local`

I'm running on windows 10, ruby 2.2.4 and capistrano 3.8.1

````
```mr@MR-LAPTOP MINGW64 ~/inpay_git/capdemo
$ cap staging foo:local -p --trace
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke foo:local (first_time)
** Execute foo:local
Config variable set: :print_config_variables => true
Config variable set: :stage => :staging
Config variable set: :scm => :"default-git"
Config variable set: :branch => "master"
Config variable set: :deploy_to => #<Proc:0x376d6a0@C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.1/lib/capistrano/defaults.rb:25 (lambda)>
Config variable set: :tmp_dir => "/tmp"
Config variable set: :default_env => {}
Config variable set: :keep_releases => 5
Config variable set: :format => :airbrussh
Config variable set: :log_level => :debug
Config variable set: :pty => false
Config variable set: :local_user => #<Proc:0x33c43f8@C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.1/lib/capistrano/defaults.rb:36 (lambda)>
Config variable set: :format => :airbrussh
Config variable set: :git_shallow_clone => false
Config variable set: :git_wrapper_path => #<Proc:0x3776310@C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.1/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:9 (lambda)>
Config variable set: :git_environmental_variables => #<Proc:0x3775d10@C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.1/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:15 (lambda)>
Config variable set: :application => "my_app_name"
Config variable set: :repo_url => "git@example.com:me/my_repo.git"
Config variable set: :scm => :git
00:00 foo:local
      01 dir
cap aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /usr/bin/env dir
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:193:in `spawn'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:193:in `popen_run'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:93:in `popen3'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:44:in `execute_command'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:74:in `execute'
C:/Users/mr/inpay_git/capdemo/lib/capistrano/tasks/foo.rake:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:70:in `run_locally'
C:/Users/mr/inpay_git/capdemo/lib/capistrano/tasks/foo.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `call'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/airbrussh-1.2.0/lib/airbrussh/rake/context.rb:62:in `execute'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
C:/Ruby/224/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby/224/bin/cap:22:in `load'
C:/Ruby/224/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => foo:local```
````

Answer (score 1):

Commands executed with Capistrano are prefixed with `/usr/bin/env` by default. If you do not have `/usr/bin/env` on your system, then the command will fail. I am not familiar with Windows, so I don't know if this is an insurmountable problem.

If you want to remove the `/usr/bin/env` prefix, you could modify Capistrano's "command map" to remove all default behavior:

```
# In deploy.rb
# NOT RECOMMENDED
SSHKit.config.command_map = SSHKit::CommandMap.new({})
```

But this will affect local *and* remote commands, which is not desirable. Again, Capistrano assumes that you want to run things identically in local vs remote environments.

If these limitations and workarounds are too restrictive, you do not have to use `run_locally`. In fact, `run_locally` is not very well supported by Capistrano anyway, and the maintainers (myself included) [discourage using it](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/252). Instead, you could can use Ruby's built-in methods for running local commands, like `system` or back-ticks.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60

Comment: Okay - so the "run_locally" method is not actually meant for running tasks locally in relation with deployment - or at least not in a cross-platform environment. Based on this feedback I wrote my own deployment strategy that uses git archive to pull the latest head from git to a locally stored tarball and upload this to the remote servers.